# How can I deserialize the following xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I want to deserialize the following xml in one class (with the specific properties):

```
<test1>
    <field1>0</field1>
    <field2>1</field2>
    <field3>2</field3>
</test1>
<test2>
    <field4>0</field4>
    <field5>1</field5>
    <field6>2</field6>
</test2>
<test3>
    <field7>0</field7>
    <field8>1</field8>
    <field9>2</field9>
</test3>
```

I've written the classes as follow:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Result
    {
        [XmlElement("test1")]
        public Test1 T1{ get; set; }

        [XmlElement("test2")]
        public Test2 T2 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("test3")]
        public Test3 T3 { get; set; }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Test1
    {
        [XmlElement("Field1")]
        public Test1 Field1{ get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Field2")]
        public Test2 Field2{ get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Field3")]
        public Test3 Field3 { get; set; }

    }
....
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error at deserialize:

> input xmlns='' was not expected.

Thanks for your help.

Kind regards, pro

Comment: Your xml does not have a *root* element

Comment: Yes I know - that is the challenge ;-)

Comment: Your xml must have one root element with name `Result`

Comment: If you are recieving the XML from a service which you cannot control why not simply read the XML into a stream then preprend & append the <Result> nodes, then deserialize the XML as a string?

Comment: @pro challenge?!!! your xml is not valid so you cannot deserialize it

Comment: The error you have posted is `input xmlns='' was not expected.` but there is no `xmlns` in the XML you have posted.  You should probably post more code, or the rest of the XML, since the error message doesn't match what you've posted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<Result>...</Result>` element around the XML. If they are missing, prepend and append them. If a different root element is present, add the `[XmlRoot("name")]` element to the `Result` class.

The easiest way to solve XML serialization problems is to populate an object then serialize it using `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` and look at the resulting XML.

Comment: I can't I get them from a webservice.

Comment: @pro There will be some root element in the resulting web service XML. Make that the name of the class or use `[XmlRoot("name")]` attribute. If not, manually append and prepend the root elements. I have updated my answer accordingly.